# How to use opcache_compile_file() in PHP?

Tags: php, caching, dependency-injection

I understand how caching works and how it improves performance. I couldn't find anywhere on the web that showed examples of this. What are the best practices?

Internally, if the `opcache_compile_file()` function is executed I'm assuming that it checks to see if the file is already cached, and if so then quickly continue to the next statement (or the performance gain would be lost) this is a bit of a rhetorical question.

Finally, I'm using dependency injection and PHP seems to already do a good job of caching functions and classes even when using DI and instantiating on the fly.

Is the opcache_compile_file() function even needed?

Comment: be clear with the codes ...u have worked on & see the edit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the opcache_compile_file() function even needed?

No, you don't need to care about that. The opcache works automatically, you have nothing to do.

Comment: You can use this function along with `opcache.file_cache` to prewarm the cache on server restart, so it is useful. Otherwise files will be compiled individually, as they are required, in response to requests.